# ffpmeg не вырезает видео

Tags: php, ffmpeg

На локальном сервере работала эта команда:

```
ffmpeg -i "файл.mp4" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -ss 00:05:00 -t 00:00:04 "часть-файла.ts"
```

Эта команда с 5-ой минуты копирует кусочек видео ролика продолжительностью 4 секунды.
Но на сервере vps эта команда копирует только звук, без видео. Почему нет видео?

Comment: Возможно, нет кодека? Что выводит ffmpeg?

Comment: а как проверить есть ли кодек?

Comment: если часть строки с определием времени старта и длительностью переместить в начало, тогда ffmpeg создает ролики с видео, но продолжительность их не соответствует заданным параметрам, создаются части очень длинные, почти на весь фильм вместо заданных 4 сенунд.
`ffmpeg -ss 00:20:34 -t 00:00:04 -i "file.mp4" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb "tp_3.ts"`

Comment: команда:
`ffmpeg -i "/home/admin/web/pornobody.ru/public_html/temp/video.mp4" -codec copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -ss 00:20:34 -t 00:00:04 "/home/admin/web/pornobody.ru/public_html/temp/tp_3.ts"`
Результат: http://pastebin.com/8uzR7JEJ